# ¿Cómo capturar la ruta de una JSP donde se haya efectuado un error?

Tags: java, sql, jsp

Básicamente lo que quiero es capturar la ruta de una *JSP* donde se haya efectuado un error.

Supongamos que tengo *10 páginas JSP* y en una de ellas hay un error en una consulta, cuando esa consulta *SQL* se daña, inmediatamente te redirige a una *JSP* llamada `errorPage`, que en esta *JSP* le muestra al cliente que hubo un error, y lo que quiero saber es cómo insertar la ruta de la *JSP* donde hubo el error en una tabla para que este sea más fácil de buscarla por la ruta.

Comment: A ver si te puede servir esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300404/how-to-show-the-requested-url-in-a-jsp-error-page

Answer (score 0):

Antes de redirigir captura el error con un bloque try/catch y en la parte del catch inserta en base de datos la ruta del jsp y el error que se ha cometido una vez insertado en base de datos ya rediriges a la página errorPage, eso lo tendrías que hacer en las 10 páginas JSP.

Comment: Oye, muchas gracias esta era la solución que necesitaba.